changes in immer store not reflective across components in nextjs14
I have created a store in nextjs using useImmer to share and mutate state on need  across several app component in nextjs. so problem is that, all the component are using the same state and setters from a single store, so the state change by any component should reflect it in other components since they are taking data from same store, rather the state change is only reflective in the component from where the change is initiated, looks like each component has its own copy of store and any state change is only observable there.  why
'use client'
import {useImmer} from 'use-immer';

const usePracticeImmer = () => {
    const initialState={
        count:0,
    };

    const [state,setState]=useImmer(initialState);

    const upCounter = () => {
        setState(draft=>{
            draft.count++
        });
    }

    const downCounter = () => {
        setState(draft=>{
            draft.count--;
        });
    };

    return {count:state.count, upCounter,downCounter}

}

export default usePracticeImmer

here are components
'use client'
import React from 'react'
import usePracticeImmer from '../../(store)/storePractice'
const Display = () => {
    const {count}=usePracticeImmer();
    console.log(count);
    const containerStyling={display:'flex',flexDirection:'column',placeItems:'center',placeContent: 'center',height:'100vh',
    fontSize:'2.4rem',color:'gray',borderRadius:'5px'};
    const textStyling= {padding:'1.4rem 3.5rem',margin:'1rem',border:'2px solid transparent',fontSize:'3.2rem'};

  return (
    <div style={containerStyling}>
      <p style={textStyling}>count is {count}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Display

2nd component
'use client'
import React from 'react'
import usePracticeImmer from '../../(store)/storePractice'
const Display = () => {
    const {count}=usePracticeImmer();
    console.log(count);
    const containerStyling={display:'flex',flexDirection:'column',placeItems:'center',placeContent: 'center',height:'100vh',
    fontSize:'2.4rem',color:'gray',borderRadius:'5px'};
    const textStyling= {padding:'1.4rem 3.5rem',margin:'1rem',border:'2px solid transparent',fontSize:'3.2rem'};

  return (
    <div style={containerStyling}>
      <p style={textStyling}>count is {count}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Display

so several components are using setters from same store but change in state is only reflective in the component from where change is initiated.
